# Javascript Animation with multiple images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I'll thy to explain the situation.
I am working on a csgo gambling website.

[image]

I have a roulette animation based on a picture with 30 slots.
{1 on the Image}

And I browsed trough some sites and then I came across this page with something similar, but the difference was that they used single images which repeats themself *I think*.
This is what ive found:
{2 on the Image}

This is what I mean , they use just images and kinda repeat them:
{3 on the Image}

I'm not sure if they generate a random pattern or if this is a custom pattern.
But it would be nice if someone could give a feedback
{4 on the Image}

All I want is just to know is what this exactly is so I can do a resarch or even better if someone could explain me how this works or how to do it.

Thanks alot

***Im sorry that the image looks bad, its because i'm not allowed to post multiple screenshots***

What I mean is not an spinning image, it mean this.
Please check this gif then you know what i mean.
Once the timer hits 0 it starts spinning
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/4264f9f4c356bc7a5e2ab10efaa90f12.gif]

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times without improving the quality of your question... Your question is too broad and is lacking effort on your part (code wise). If you have a specific issue, please create a working example with your code so we can help you.

Comment: Why did you delete the *exact* same question a few minutes before posting this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107709/animated-image-spinner

Comment: i didnt knew how to update it :/  im not really much on stackoverflow thats why im a noob

Comment: but even now i have no idea how to explain that. the gif should show the rolling animation, and its build off an array i think but i dont know how to do this thats why im looking for help over here

Comment: Yeah Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. We're not here to write websites for you. So you're going to need to learn how to do most of this on your own, and if you have any **specific issues** with it, you can come back and ask.

Comment: Hunter Turner i know .. im not here for getting spoonfeeded. god no , im just here to get any ideas off peoples for what im looking for . i need to know how this thing is called so i can do a deeper research on it to code it by myself. i just need like hints where to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for [`roulette.js` (click here)](http://demo.st-marron.info/roulette/sample/demo.html) which is a javascript library that exactly does the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks this is for example something ive meant ! now thats a good start for me :)

Comment: Accept the answer then (green check mark near the voting arrows) ;) And have fun!